# W/flutter (22164): onAdFailedToLoad: 0

Tags: flutter

I am having issues with my ads that i put on my app. here is the error:

```
W/flutter (22164): onAdFailedToLoad: 0
I/Ads     (22164): Ad failed to load : 0
W/flutter (22164): onAdFailedToLoad: 0
I/Ads     (22164): Ad failed to load : 0
I/flutter (22164): InterstitialAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
I/flutter (22164): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
```

pls help me solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR) about this problem.

According to this documentation, error code 0 means internal error. Actually internal error itself doesn't tell us some specific information but it usually happens when you just opened your ad.

So wait a little bit till it works.